# Construct a singular positive semidefinite matrix with bounded trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am wondering if there exists nontrivial singular $n\times n$ positive semidefinite matrix $A$ such that $\operatorname{Tr}A\leq n$. If this is the case, how should I construct it. Here's my first try.

Start with the diagonal matrix $D=\operatorname{diag}(1, 0 ,0)$. Then I need to find  some orthogonal matrix $U \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ such that $A=UDU^{T}$ and that $A$ is positive semidefinite. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, we can calculate $$\langle x,Ax\rangle=\langle U^Tx,DU^Tx\rangle=(U^Tx)_1^2=(u_{11}x_1+u_{21}x_2+u_{31}x_3)^2,$$ and this quantity must be bigger than $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$. Now it seems that it is quite impossible to me that I can have any candidate of $(u_{11}, u_{21},u_{31})$. How should I tackle the problem? Thanks for any comments!

Comment: Take $x$ as and eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$, you have $\langle x,Ax\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facts:

- $\text{Tr}(A)$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ (counted with algebraic multiplicity).
- $A$ is singular if at least one of its eigenvalue is zero

Your $D$ is perfectly fine: the trace (which equals the sum of the eigenvalues) is $1$ and there is at least one zero eigenvalue. Your $A$ also works, for any choice of $U$; note that  $A=UDU^\top$ is also symmetric with the same eigenvalues as $D$, so it is also singular with trace $1$.

I'm not quite sure why you are asking that $\langle x, Ax \rangle \le \langle x, x \rangle$; this does not seem related to your original question.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I've corrected. Do you mean that $\langle x,Ax\rangle\geq \langle x,x\rangle$ for any choice of orthogonal matrix $U$? How can I prove it?

Comment: @inbrevi "$\langle x, Ax \rangle \ge \langle x,x \rangle$ for any $x$" means all the eigenvalues of $A$ are at least $1$. This has nothing to do with the desired conditions "singular" and "$\text{Tr}(A) \le n$," so I am not sure why you bring it up. If $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$, then $\langle x, A x\rangle = 0$, so it cannot be larger than $\langle x, x \rangle$.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I know where my problem is. Thanks a lot for your explanation ;)